# Testing Mongoose Validations with Jest expect.toThrow

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I would like to create a test to ensure that if I miss a required field, the service throws an error.

This is my schema:

```
export const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    passwordHash: String
});
```

And this is my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>) {}

    async create(createUserDto): Promise<User> {
        const createdUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
        return await createdUser.save();
    }
}
```

And in my service test I have this case:

```
it('Validates required email', async () => {
        const dto = {
            firstName: 'Test',
            lastName: 'User',
            passwordHash: '123ABC'
        };

        expect( async () => {
            return await service.create(dto);
        }).toThrowError(/required/);

    });
```

But the test fails, with this message:

```
    Expected the function to throw an error matching:
      /required/
    But it didn't throw anything.
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should modify your test case like this:

```
it('Validates required email', async () => {
        const dto = {
            firstName: 'Test',
            lastName: 'User',
            passwordHash: '123ABC'
        };

        await expect(service.create(dto)).rejects.toThrowError(ValidationError); //probably will be error of this type

    });
```

Comment: This answer helped me test my Mongoose validation!
My code which ended up working: `expect(invalidUserEmailModel.save()).rejects.toThrowError(ValidationError);`

Answer (score 0):

Answer by myself. The trick is to use expect.assertions and try catch:

```
expect.assertions(1);
try {
    await service.create(dto);
} catch (error) {
    expect(error.message).toMatch(/required/);
}
```